# Applet calculation & listener issue & appearance

Tags: java, exception, applet, try-catch, actionlistener

The following applet shows up in a bundled mess when launched but the bigger issue is that when the button is pressed to calculate, exceptions fly.  I'm not sure what the issue could be.  I'm pretty sure my loop is correct.

Here's a list of the exceptions then the actual code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:992)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at bacCalcApplet$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(bacCalcApplet.java:164)
    at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:392)
    at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:360)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4737)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:684)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:657)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:655)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:654)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

### Code

```
//@author Noah Kline

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;

public class bacCalcApplet extends Applet
{

/**
 * Calculates the BAC
 */
// Create Panel Properties
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8477155615510893945L;
private Panel fPanel;
private Panel answerPanel;
private Panel dPanel;
private Panel wPanel;
private Panel hPanel;
private Panel buttonPanel;
private TextField genderDisplay;
private TextField drinksCount;
private TextField weightDisplay;
private TextField hoursDisplay;
private TextField bacDisplay;

public void init()
{
    // Initialize panels
    buildGenderpanel();
    buildDrinkpanel();
    buildWeightpanel();
    buildHourspanel();
    buildanswerPanel();
    buildButtonPanel();

    // panel layout design in 1 applet
    setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));

    // adding panel properties to layout
    add(fPanel);
    add(dPanel);
    add(wPanel);
    add(answerPanel);
    add(buttonPanel);

}

private void buildGenderpanel()
{

    fPanel = new Panel();

    Label message1 = new Label("Enter Gender:");

    genderDisplay = new TextField(10);

    fPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    fPanel.add(message1);
    fPanel.add(genderDisplay);

}

private void buildDrinkpanel()
{

    dPanel = new Panel();

    Label message2 = new Label("Enter # of Drinks:");

    drinksCount = new TextField(10);

    fPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    fPanel.add(message2);
    fPanel.add(drinksCount);

}

private void buildWeightpanel()
{

    wPanel = new Panel();

    Label message3 = new Label("Enter Your Weight:");

    weightDisplay = new TextField(10);

    wPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    wPanel.add(message3);
    wPanel.add(weightDisplay);

}

private void buildHourspanel()
{

    hPanel = new Panel();

    Label message4 = new Label("Enter Hours since last drink: ");

    hoursDisplay = new TextField(10);

    hPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    hPanel.add(message4);
    hPanel.add(hoursDisplay);

}

private void buildanswerPanel()
{

    answerPanel = new Panel();

    Label message5 = new Label("Answer: ");

    bacDisplay = new TextField(10);

    // answerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    bacDisplay.setEditable(false);

    answerPanel.add(message5);
    answerPanel.add(bacDisplay);

}

private void buildButtonPanel()
{

    buttonPanel = new Panel();

    Button convButton = new Button("Calculate");

    convButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    buttonPanel.add(convButton);
}

// Listener
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        double gender;
        double drinks;
        double weight;
        double hours;
        double bac;

        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

        gender = Double.parseDouble(genderDisplay.getText());

        drinks = Double.parseDouble(drinksCount.getText());

        weight = Double.parseDouble(weightDisplay.getText());

        hours = Double.parseDouble(hoursDisplay.getText());

        bac = Double.parseDouble(bacDisplay.getText());

        if (gender == 1)
        {
            bac = ((drinks * .06 * 100 * 1.055) / (weight * .68))
                    - (0.015 * hours);

            bacDisplay.setText(fmt.format(bac));

        }

        else if (gender == 2)
        {

            bac = ((drinks * .06 * 100 * 1.055) / (weight * .55))
                    - (0.015 * hours);

            bacDisplay.setText(fmt.format(bac));

        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: The logic should be relatively straightforward with the BAC calculation.

Comment: `gender = Double.parseDouble(genderDisplay.getText());`  Since when is gender a double value?!?  (My gender is `231.746` BTW.)

Comment: 1) BTW - this is the 3rd millennium, use Swing.  2) Gender should be a combo or group of radio buttons. 3) Why an applet as opposed to a frame?

Comment: I could not successfully get radio buttons to work at all so I tried this input.  I want to put this online so I am not using a frame.

Comment: I already responded to the first question by saying that I was not successfully able to get radio buttons working.  I will look into Web Start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final product, minus an applet (built with jQuery):  http://bac.klinetel.com/